# Mysterious date/time in file metadata. (Windows 10/NTFS?)

Tags: windows-10

I have a certain folder where I need to sort items by date.

Recently I copied this folder to a new location. I use [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) to make the copy, which:

> copies
>   Alternative Streams on files and folders
>   EA Records on files and folders (rarely used)
>   Reparse Info
>   File Attributes
>   **Timestamps: Creation Time, Last Access Time, Last Write Time**
>   Sparse Files and Alternative Sparse Streams
>   Encrypted files
>   ACLs

I also access it via an SMB share on my android phone. The app there can also sort by date. However it displays dates I cannot find ANYWHERE in the files. They are not the created/modifed/accesssed dates. No detail column from Windows Explorer contains that date. It's the time of the copy. Perhaps tellingly, this behaviour is observed only when copying. If the files are moved(cut), the dates are preserved.

Can someone shed some light on this? What kind of datetimes are stored in files?
(*note: This 100% has nothing to do with the android side, please do not go that route.*)

Also, what does the "Accessed" date do? It doesn't seem to change when I open the file.

Comment: How did you _verify_ that this is not caused by a buggy Android client? Strong claims need strong evidence.

Comment: Tested on 2 different devices and on a clean install of the app I used. There is no way for both devices or a clean install to acquire the same date, without taking it from the source of the file (rather than, say, its own internal metadata or something).

Comment: I strongly suspect it is in fact creation time, but is offset by some amount due to bugs in the app's code (clean install of a bad app is still a bad app) _or_ in the SMB server, if it isn't Windows-based. Could you show a few specific examples, with all Explorer times and the Android time as well?

Comment: SMB Server is windows' built in. Your hypothesis does not make sense given that I have files ranging from 2008 to now. Yet the wrongly reported dates match to the time of the copy. 1. If there was an offset it's awfully inconsistent. 2. Why is it exactly the time of the copy and not some other random time? 3. I can replicate that with new copies. I copy something now. It shows up as now in the app. Here is an example: https://imgur.com/a/q5RoASJ  I truly am 100% certain it is not on the android side.

Answer (score 1):

> Yet the wrongly reported dates match to the time of the copy. [...] Why is it exactly the time of the copy and not some other random time?
>
> It's the time of the copy. Perhaps tellingly, this behaviour is observed only when copying. If the files are moved(cut), the dates are preserved.

After re-reading it more carefully, your description exactly matches the way 'Date Created' timestamps work in Windows.

If the files are moved (within the same volume), they still stay the same files and retain all attributes. But if the files are copied, the destination is a completely new file and only retains those attributes that the copying program *manually* carries over. (There is no "duplicate this whole file" system call.)

So whereas Explorer manually carries over the 'Modified' timestamps from the original to the copy, the 'Created' timestamps are deliberately left as-is and represent when *this particular filesystem object* was created.

> They are not the created/modifed/accesssed dates. No detail column from Windows Explorer contains that date.

You are most likely looking at the wrong files, e.g. checking timestamps of the original instead of the copy.

In all versions of Windows that I have tested while writing this post (ranging from Win98 to Win10.1903 and Win2016), the 'Date Created' column in Explorer Details view and the 'Created' field in Properties dialog always represent the time that this particular copy was made.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, given the information I gave. I did forget to mention one critical bit piece of information, which I only now discovered - I use [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) to copy the files (I have hardlinks I want to preserve). One welcome side-benefit is that it preserves timestamps. I thought explorer copy did so too, but as you described, that is not the case. I will edit the question.